# Using Spring Data JPA/MongoDB Cross Store, can a query go across both databases?

Tags: java, mongodb, jpa, spring-data

I'm using the mongodb-customer-service-data examples (available at https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-document-examples).

The example uses @RelatedDocument to associate domain objects across databases.  It allows storing and updating objects well enough.

However, I want to do a Query that has Criteria against both the JPA database (in the example HSQLDB) and MongoDB.

Is this even possible?  Is there any example anywhere that proves that it is possible?

---

Comments not directly related to the issue:

My use case is that our application is an Oracle DB, but we are now starting to receive semi-structured data.  The JPA Entities are filterable by a user within certain constraints, but we'd like to expand this capability to the semi-structured data.

There also seems to be competing technologies QueryDSL and EclipseLink, but I can't find anything about doing queries across databases.

In JPA, it doesn't appear to be possible to do cross database queries because there are different PersistanceUnits that are associated with each database.  However, mongodb cross-store seems to negate this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

I never used Spring Data JPA, but if JPA isn't capable of doing this I doubt that Spring Data will offer such capabilities.
I don't know what you understand by mongodb cross-store. So I'll explain shortly what mongodb can and can't do.

With mongodb you can't have queries across multiple collections (tables), so you can't do join with plain mongodb. So @RelatedDocument is a feature which Spring Data offers. Related documents may be either embedded (don't know if Spring Data supports this) or may be some simple DBRef to a document within a different collection (and database). With DBRef you can only query on @RelatedDocument fields like _id, collection and database, but none of the actual referenced documents property.

This said mongodb doesn't allow to search cross database in a single query, as you can't do queries across collections so you can't do this against databases either. The only cross-store functionality you have, is for sharded collections. With this you have you collection distributed across multiple nodes through a shardkey. MongoDB may need to query across all collection shards to fulfill your query. But beside this, what I wouldn't call actually a cross-database function, you have no such capabilities.

If this doesn't help, please explain in more detail what you want todo.